# Как найти не используемые CSS?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, оптимизация

Существует ли какой-нибудь онлайн сервис, чтобы в одно окно можно было вставить `html`-код страницы, в другое `css`-файл и он выдал какие стили не используются в `html` (на них нет ни одной ссылки в коде).

Или для ПК может софт какой есть для этого?

Comment: @fosh4455 у вас сайт из одной страницы состоит? Есть несколько нюансов такой очистки. Используете какую нибудь автоматизацию для CSS, JS вроде Gulp, Grunt? Пре-, пост-, процессоры CSS?

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-uncss убирает уже неиспользуемые на странице стили

Answer (score 2, accepted):

F12 в Google Chrome Developer Tools и смотрим вкладку Audits там секцию "Remove unused CSS rules". Запускаем, смотрим результаты

Comment: У меня 60ая версия, вкладка Audits есть, но там нет того, что вы говорите. Вероятно у вас доп.плагин установлен.

Comment: @AndreyFedorov, в Audits запускаете "run" ждете и раскрываете списки http://prntscr.com/g3fnrl

Answer (score 0):

Подобная функция доступна в [хроме](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/04/devtools-release-notes) версии 59+

Answer (score 0):

в gulp(система сбора веб-приложений) есть task`и, которые могут  выполнять разного рода обыденные действия, например минимизировать файлы css, js и т.д. Добавлять префиксы, сжимать jpg, png и тому подобное, его легко выучить, только немного нужно знать js, будет проще. Если хочешь можешь мне файлы скинуть, я их прогоню и удалит тебе css ненужный

Comment: Да я программер так-то gulp не юзаю обычно, так ставил его на 1 комп познакомиться... Верстаю немного для себя чисто